# Batch convert .dwg to pdf/image by deleting certain layers

Tags: autocad, dwg

I have certain .dwg files as input, I want raster images as output which contain only certain layers. I found one method for parsing one .dwg file but I want to know if there exist any methods or APIs that I could speed up this process cause I need to construct a dataset.

Thanks,

Zizhao

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Now I did it manually, but I hope I could do with Python, other languages are also acceptable.